# Displaying data based on type of user authentication

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, ag-grid

So I am have made a laravel authentication application that can log in/register users based on a type and depending on a type they can see different information in this case data tables. I used the laratrust package to do this and works well, but if I want to make this with a vue component that will show the data using some special data grid how would go about doing it as the controller which I am using where the data is collected but is also the place where the view which the user will see depending on the type of user is also checked. So, how will I send the json data to the vue component and what other things do I need to consider.
Here is the controller in laravel:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    if(Auth::user()->hasRole('user')){
        $posts = DB::select('select * from office');
        return view('userdash',['posts'=>$posts]);
    }elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole('administrator')){
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('administratordash',['posts'=>$posts]);
    }elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
     $people = DB::select('select * from office');
     $posts = Post::all();
     return view('dashboard',['posts'=>$posts,'people'=>$people]);
    }
}
}
```

One of the things I tried was

```
return response(view('userdash',array('posts'=>$posts)),200,['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);
```

This way I can just send the json data and then render it in the view component. But I am not sure if it is working as I get back a bunch of html and some of the data in the database but not all of it. Also not sure how this can be passed to the view component. Maybe as a prop but not sure.

Any and all help and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are responding from the controller with different views, you can just check for any variables sent with the wiew in your view and once your variables are at your disposal in the view yo can serialize them using `$myVar=$myVariable->toJson()` if they are laravel collections or `json_encode($myVariable)` if they are simple arrays.
Then you can

`<my-component :data ={{$myVar}}/>`

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what you mean by $people ? my idea was that I some how pass the $posts variable as json data to the view and loop through the data there

Comment: In one case you are responding with `return view('dashboard',['posts'=>$posts,'people'=>$people])`. In that case if $people collection is not empty you´ll have a variable `$people` with that collection in your view. That's what I meant.

Comment: Oh no $people is just a variable name for another table I just made 2 tables for the last user

Comment: I have edited my answer in order to add clarity to explanation.

Comment: So just to understand this $myVar=$myVariable->toJson() will be done where like in the controller right? and if yes after the first select statement right?

Comment: and when I pass in the variable to the view I should do something like `return view('userdash',['myVar'=>$myVar]);` ?

Comment: Json conversion must be done in the view unless you are not using the collection in blade at all. Then you can pass serialized data directly to the view. I do not know what type of data are you expecting in your view. If your view is expecting an array or a json obcet or a collection is your task to provide the view with the correct data format.